# Displaying a dialog from an application launched by a service

Tags: .net, windows, service, dialog

I am in of a scenario where a `.NET` application needs to be launched from a windows service created in .NET (non interactive application though).

But finally a dialog is to be displayed from the application (NOT FROM SERVICE) for prompting the user that it is completed and some relevant details.

Will there be any problem if I use this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, windows service works in an isolated session and does not have access to the desktop.
I'd suggest you to start your desktop application on user logon, then interact with the service and show dialog on need.

Comment: yes I heard that there will be problems since a service uses a non-interactive work station. But here I am trying to display the dialog from the application not from the service...

Comment: but you're trying to run application in the same user context the service is running